# Getting ExceptionInIntilizerError

Tags: java

while i am trying to run the following code iam getting ExceptionInInitilizerError instead of NullPointerException. why?

```
static 
{
   String s= null;
   System.out.println(s.length()); 
}
```

Comment: Because your class can not be initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the static initializer block, errors are not handled as they would be in the rest of your code.  When an error is thrown in the initializer block, the JVM throws `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.  This will also occur when initialization of a static variable fails.

Answer (score 2):

Static blocks are the part of class code in java which are called when the class is loaded for the first time . If you carefully look at the exception you receive :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:8)
```

You have a NullPointerException wrapped in an ExceptionInitializerError. 
Hence you received a NullPointerException and because that error occurred at a space where normal execution further was not possible , as a result you got ExceptionInitializaterError

Answer (score 0):

This is because loader is seeing error when initializing this class. If you see internal stack trace, you will find NullPointerException. But since it was the process of initializing class when loader saw the error, you are seeing this 'ExceptionInInitilizerError'.